# Merge two dataframe in pandas with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Hello I would need to merge two dataframe

The first has Two column

df1

```
Groups Names
G1    SeqA
G1    Seq1(+)
G1    SeqC
G1    Seq2(-)
G1    Seq3(+)
G1    SeqB
G1    SeqG
G2    Seq8(-)
G2    SeqY
G2    SeqH
G3    Seq10(+)
G3    SeqK
G3    Seq12(-)
```

and another one such as  df2:

```
COL1    COL2  COL3
Seq1(+) SeqA  89
Seq2(-) SeqA  67
Seq3(+) SeqB  89
Seq2(-) SeqC  98
Seq8(-) SeqY  45
Seq8(-) SeqH  90
Seq10(+) SeqK 76
Seq11(-) SeqL 78
Seq12(-) SeqK 89
```

and the idea is to kind of merge the two dataframe in order to add `Groups` information into the `df2`.

And the idea would be to first check in `df1` for each element in `Names`, if this element has a `(+)` or a `(-)`,then check its corresponding `Group` and then go on the `df2` and add at the column `Group` the corresponding `Group`.

Here for instance in `df1` `line 2` there is the `Seq1(+)`, its `Group` is `G1`, then I look for the line in `df2` where `Seq1(+)` is present in `COL1` and I add `G1` to the column Group.

So at the end I should get something like :

```
Group COL1 COL2 COL3
G1 Seq1(+) SeqA 89
G1 Seq2(-) SeqA 67
G1 Seq3(+) SeqB 89
G1 Seq2(-) SeqC 98
G2 Seq8(-) SeqY 45
G2 Seq8(-) SeqH 90 
G3 Seq10(+) SeqK 76
G3 Seq12(-) SeqK 89
```

As you can see `Seq11(-)` is not present in the last df merged because it was not present in the `df1` for `G3`

Does anyone have an idea using python and pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on='Names', right_on='COL1').drop('Names', axis=1)


Groups  COL1    COL2    COL3
0   G1  Seq1(+) SeqA    89
1   G1  Seq2(-) SeqA    67
2   G1  Seq2(-) SeqC    98
3   G1  Seq3(+) SeqB    89
4   G2  Seq8(-) SeqY    45
5   G2  Seq8(-) SeqH    90
6   G3  Seq10(+)    SeqK    76
7   G3  Seq12(-)    SeqK    89
```